# Get id stepper added programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to add an action to a stepper added programmatically, but I don't know how to get which stepper is clicked. I have a NSMutableArray where I change the values, but I want to know which stepper is clicked. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.


for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    //Here I create the stepper
    UIStepper *steperCode = [[UIStepper alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, (i*30)+120, 300, 200)];
    steperCode.maximumValue = 1000;
    steperCode.minimumValue = 0;
    steperCode.stepValue=1.0;
    [self.view addSubview:steperCode];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
    {
    UIStepper * stepperCode = [[UIStepper alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 60, 300, 200)];
    [steperCode addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    stepperCode.maximumValue = 10;
    stepperCode.minimumValue = 0;
    stepperCode.stepValue=2.0;
    stepperCode.tag = i;
    [self.view addSubview:stepperCode];
    }
}

- (IBAction)valueChanged:(UIStepper *)sender
{
   NSLog(@"Changed stepper num :%i",sender.tag);
}
```